# SQL Import live data from external website to sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to import the premier league table into a table of my own on a weekly basis as seen on googles search:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=premier+league+table&oq=premier+l&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j0j69i57j69i59j0.2230j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

[image: premier league snapshot]

I already have my own database table with all the premier league teams in it and information on all their players but I would like to also display this information also.

How would I go about this so that I can then query the table for calculations of my own?

Comment: what language were you wanting to scrape in?

Comment: @JasonMArcher I didn't know of the terminology scraping until now but if possible SQL?

Comment: not really.  SQL is a query language, and is usually manipulated in computation with some other language.  So you could make your queries in a language which cal SQL to carry out its given commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would scrape the page, and then run it through a parser.  To me, i would run it through something you might know.  Then scrape it for something like:

```
div.lr_container table.vk_tbl > tbody > tr
```

and then look over the array of rows and insert into your db.

Comment: Can you point me into the right direction to begin learning how to 'scrape'

Comment: well, it really depends on the language you are trying to do.  I usually scrape with PHP, because i *kinda* enjoy that language.  That would be something like:   `$url = 'something.com/hello.html'; $data = file_get_contents($url);` From there you could save the file locally, or pip it into some sort of parsing tool.  Just about every language though has an option for essentially saving a document, whether its on the internet or locally.